# Dynamic intersections between groups based on relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

product_facet_values_facet_value

```
+-----------+--------------+
| productId | facetValueId |
+-----------+--------------+
|         6 |            1 |
|         6 |           34 |
|         7 |           39 |
|         8 |           34 |
|         8 |            1 |
|         8 |           11 |
|         9 |            1 |
|         9 |           39 |
+-----------+--------------+
```

facet_value

```
+--------------+---------+
| facetValueId | facetId |
+--------------+---------+
|            1 |       2 |
|           34 |       6 |
|           39 |       2 |
|           44 |       2 |
|           56 |      11 |
+--------------+---------+
```

I need to be able to get all productIds with those facetValueIds I ask for but with one extra step - I need an **intersection** between facetValueId groups based on same facetId.

For example I want to get all product ids with facetValueId 1, 34, 39 and result of this query should be same as I would get with the following query:

```
select "productId"
from "product_facet_values_facet_value"
where "facetValueId" in (1, 39) 
INTERSECT 
select "productId"
from "product_facet_values_facet_value"
where "facetValueId" in (34)
```

I wrote this query based on: facetValueIds 1 or 39 has same "facetId"=2, facetValueId 34 has "facetId"=6.

I need a query that would result in same result without having it to group it manually. If for example next time I ask for all products that have facetValueIds 1, 34, 39, 56 the result of such dynamic query should be same as if I would write 3 INTERSECTIONs between IN (1, 39) & IN(34) & IN(56) like:

```
select "productId"
from "product_facet_values_facet_value"
where "facetValueId" in (1, 39) 
INTERSECT 
select "productId"
from "product_facet_values_facet_value"
where "facetValueId" in (34)
INTERSECT 
select "productId"
from "product_facet_values_facet_value"
where "facetValueId" in (56)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The result should be a list of productIds that have "1 and 34" or "39 and 34".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d06344b4a68c7b97fc1fad46c7437894

This is the same method as @a_horse_with_no_name used, but generalised very slightly.

```
WITH
   targets AS
(
  SELECT * FROM facet_value WHERE facetId IN (2, 6)
)
SELECT
  map.productId
FROM
  product_facet_values_facet_value   AS map
INNER JOIN
  targets                            AS tgt
    ON tgt.facetValueId = map.facetValueId
GROUP BY
  map.productId
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT tgt.facetId) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT facetId) FROM targets)
```

Comment: Great! This helped me a lot, I just had to switch facetId for "id" as I'm looking for facetValueIds and just group them based on facetId.